# Compare each row in one dataframe to each row in another dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different dataframes with the same features.

df1

```
   AGE   Country     Income
   -----------------------
   33    UK          3500
   24    Australia   1500
```

df2

```
   AGE   Country     Income
   -----------------------
   33    Brazil      1300
   54    Australia   2230
```

I would like to compare each row in df1 to each row df2, and compute the number of differences found in the features values.

In my example, we have 2 dataframes, each dataframe has 2 instances. So, will have 4 sort of comparisons.

For each comparison, i need to return the number of features differences. For example, if we compare the first row in df1 to the first row in df2, we will have 2 differences in the feature values.

Any idea how to implement that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If the data are not too long, broadcast is the way to go.

Comment: Are these dataframes the same length?

Comment: the dataframes are in different length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, an approach would be to use `np.where()` and to calculate for each feature individually the number of differences per row and sum these arrays:

```
arr = np.where(df_1['Age']!=df_2['Age'],1,0) + np.where(df_1['Country'] != df_2['Country'],1,0) + np.where(df_1['Income']!=df_2['Income'],1,0)
```

This will return an array with the number of feature-differences per each row. In this case, the output would be:

```
[2,2]
```

If there are many columns like in the example below, you can use a for loop:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[1,2,3,4],'Country':['Brazil','UK','Australia','China'],'Var_x':[7,5,7,7],'Var_y':[3,6,3,2],'Var_z':[20,32,31,34]}) 
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[1,2,4,5],'Country':['Egypt','UK','India','China'],'Var_x':[7,4,3,7],'Var_y':[3,6,2,2],'Var_z':[20,32,4,32]})
differences = np.zeros(len(df_1))
for i in df_1:
  differences += np.where(df_1[i]!=df_2[i],1,0)
print(differences)
```

Output:

```
[1. 1. 5. 2.]
```

Comment: your second solution with a for loop is ok. But the problem is, it only compares the 1st row in df_1 with the 1st row in df_2, the the 2nd row in df_1 with a 2nd row in df_2, the 3rd row from df_1 to the 3rd row in df_2, and the 4th row in df_1 to the 4th row in df_2. The output consists of 4 numbers. It is right. BUT what i really need is to take the first row in df_1 and compare it to all rows in df_2, and then take the second row in df_1 and compare it with all rows in df_2. and so on. we should have 16 comparison. and the output would be an array of 16 digit not just 4